# how to install and use ng2-datepicker-bootstrap version 0.1.2

Tags: angular, datepicker

I installed the ng2-datepicker-bootstrap as following because I am using angular 2:
  npm install ng2-datepicker-bootstrap@0.1.2 --save

The installation only contains source files (ts files), which does not have compiled js files. I believe I have to compile it before I can use it. If I need, how can I do it?
Thanks in advance!

**Added**:
Thanks @MattHolland. That's what I am confused. In the README for 0.1.2, it says:

````
Update the system.config
```
var map = {
    ....
    'ng2-datepicker-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-datepicker-bootstrap/dist'
};
````

But there is not "dist" folder at all. The installed only contains source files such as .ts, .html, etc. No compiled js file found.

Comment: You can access the README for 0.1.2 via https://github.com/rodolfocop/ng2-datepicker-bootstrap/tree/21a8b4998a50d74e7d10b6296417791b53688587 - does this help?

Comment: Thanks @MattHolland. Please see my added.

Comment: You're right, it seems like something was overlooked by the library authors when it was published to NPM. There is a similar GitHub issue, but that could actually be you as well! https://github.com/rodolfocop/ng2-datepicker-bootstrap/issues/8

Comment: @MattHolland Yes, that's me ~_~

Comment: Can anyone help me?